# Apply font on every pages - NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a `nextjs` app and I applied a Google font on my `app/layout.tsx` :

Problem : this font is applied only on `/` and not on other pages.
Is `layout.tsx` made to apply to all children ?

```
import "styles/global.css";
import {Metadata} from "next";
import {Gabarito} from "next/font/google";

const gabarito = Gabarito({
    weight: ["500", "600", "700", "900"],
    style: ["normal"],
    display: "swap",
    subsets: ["latin"],
});

export default function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    return (
        <html lang='fr' className={gabarito.className}>
            <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "...",
    description: "...",
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

> this font is applied only on / and not on other pages. Is layout.tsx made to apply to all children

**Possible Causes :**

- Improper Tailwind CSS Configuration.
- Missing `'./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'` this line in
  `tailwind.config.js` content key.

**Solution :**

As per the official documentation,

Go to your `tailwind.config.js` & add update `content` key to

```
content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
```

Also in your `app/globals.css` dont forget to add :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind.config.js :**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [

    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',

    // Or if using `src` directory:
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {

    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

***Please Read :***

- **Configuring Tailwind :**  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/tailwind-css#configuring-tailwind

> ***If you still have any doubts, please leave a comment (i will update answer).***

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. This is already what I have in my `tailwind.config` unfortunately. I don't think it comes from tailwind since the doc don't mention tailwind : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#google-fonts

Comment: I pasted your above code in layout , it works on myside as expected. I'm using NextJS `13.5.6` . I also tried moving `className={gabarito.className}` in body tag & also in html tag, font was applied on all pages in both of the above cases. 
*Please update the above question with your code for `tailwind.config`, `layout.tsx`, `nextjs version` & folder structure.*

Comment: *Where was the problem ?*

Comment: I had a warning saying that the font could not be overwrited so I switched to an import on css file and apply the font on tailwind.config. Thanks for your help mate !